# How to access the property of an object inside an array

Tags: php, oop

I have this simple object inside an array, which I want to grab the 'total' property and store it in a variable. I've looked at similar posts and none of them worked, does anyone have a solution?

Thanks! :)

PHP:

```
array (size=1)
    0 =>
        object(stdClass)[29]
            public 'total' => string '15' (length=2)
```

Comment: `$x = $myArray[0]->total;`

Comment: I wonder then, what were those similar posts that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
$obj = $array[0];
echo $obj->total;
```

If it does not work for you, that means you have not included class definition file and that the script doesn't know of which class is the object an instance of. You can do it on top of php file or use __autoload function to include that definition when needed.